# How do I add custom column to woocommerce cart?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add a custom column for "Installation Charges" inside cart items. This is going to be different installation charges for every product. I can pass that to cart using woocommerce_add_cart_item_data action hook. But how do I add the separate column to show these installation charges in cart?

Attached is a screenshot mockup of how it needs to be built.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite the WooCommerce template in your theme. The documentation for this can be found at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

The file you're looking to overwrite is `wp-content/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey but I am actually working on a plugin, so not allowed to touch the theme files. Is there some action or filter hooks to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm... Based on the code of that file, there are not available hooks to alter the table columns. You could take a look at this old article from 2012 https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/ basically meaning that themes can still override your file but if you tell them that you've done so in the plugin they can copy that instead and it should all be fine.

Comment: I just tried the method from old article but theme is already overriding the template files, so it's not working.

Comment: Well with that same method you can take away the check for WC templates in the theme and force it to only check in your plugin but then no one will use your plugin. It's simply not gonna happen ;)